# Pairwise distances of points and classification using GraphDistanceMatrix

Tags: programming, graphs-and-networks, performance-tuning

## The challenge

Given $n$ points in $\mathbf{R}^3$ and a cutoff distance, $d$, I would like to determine

1. all pairs of points that are separated by less than the given cutoff distance, $d$, and
2. all pairs of points that can be connected by less than 5 segments taken from the list of pairs from above.

While this is straight-forward for small $n$, for large $n$ the simplistic approach given below is slow (searching for the pairs) and memory consuming (GraphDistanceMatrix seems to return a dense matrix). How could this problem be solved efficiently for $n$ of order 30000?

## Inefficient sample code:

Generate sample data:

```
n = 1000; (* desired: n=20000 *)
pos = RandomReal[{0, n^(1/3)-1}, {n, 3}];
```

Find close points (ad 1):

```
d = 0.8;
connected = Select[Subsets[Range[n], {2}], (Norm[pos[[#[[1]]]] - pos[[#[[2]]]]] < d)&];
```

Pairs of points closer than 5 leaps apart (ad 2):

```
v = Union[Flatten[connected]];
g = Graph[v,UndirectedEdge @@@ connected];
gdm = GraphDistanceMatrix[g, 4];
ind = 
  Select[Position[gdm, Alternatives[1, 2, 3, 4], {2}], (#[[1]] < #[[2]])&] /. 
    Thread[Range[Length[v]] -> v];
```

Comment: to all: I found it difficult to accept one of the answers. All three contributions were enlightening and helpful. I have eventually accepted szabolcs answer, because I enjoyed being reminded of the direct use of adjacency matrices and the fact that the built-in tools are not always superior. However, I want to point out that belisarius was the first to introduce the use of the NearestFunction, which all other answers have retained (even though it accepts all points at distances <=d, instead of <d), and halmir was the first presenting a complete answer. Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
n = 20000;(*desired:n=20000*)SeedRandom[42];
pos = RandomReal[{0, n^(1/3) - 1}, {n, 3}];
d = 0.8;
f = Nearest[pos -> Range[n]];
pos1 = f[#, {Infinity, d}] & /@ pos;
```

Starting from belisarius's `pos1`, we can efficiently solve task 2 like this:

1. build the adjacency matrix of the graph as a sparse array:

   ```
   am = SparseArray[Flatten[Thread /@ Thread[{pos1, Range[n]}], 1] -> 1];
   ```
2. the $k^\text{th}$ power of the adjacency matrix $A$ will tell us which nodes are connected by precisely $k$ hops.  Since this particular adjacency matrix `am` has all ones on the diagonal, its $k^\text{th}$ power will tell us which nodes are connected by $k$ *or fewer* hops:

   ```
   am5 = Unitize@MatrixPower[am, 5];
   ```

All this takes 0.14 seconds on my machine when starting with `n=20000` as belisarius did:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 am = SparseArray[Flatten[Thread /@ Thread[{pos1, Range[n]}], 1] -> 1];
 am5 = Unitize@MatrixPower[am, 5];
]

(* ==> {0.141265, Null} *)
```

Use [`ArrayRules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ArrayRules.html) to extract the pairs (edges) from a sparse adjacency matrix.

Comment: _the fifth power of the adjacency matrix will tell us which nodes are connected by no more than five steps_ : `AdjacencyGraph@
 Unitize@MatrixPower[AdjacencyMatrix[GridGraph[{2, 2}]], 2]`

Comment: @belisarius It seems I'm particularly stupid today.  Does it look fine now?

Comment: Yep :) +1 Now :)

Comment: @Szabolcs and belisarius: Thus, the Total and the NestList are superfluous, arn't they? Very elegant and efficient solution! Thank you very much!

Comment: @user11977 Be careful, it's not superfluous.  If $A$ is the adjacency matrix, then $A^k$ is the adjacency matrix for connections possible through *precisely* $k$ hops, not less or more.  So we need to sum up all of $A, A^2, \ldots, A^k$ to get the connections possible through $k$ hops or less.

Comment: @szabolcs You are certainly right. However, as far as I can tell, "am" from above is the adjacency matrix plus the identity matrix. Thus, the summation is implicit, isn't it?

Comment: @user11977 Yes, you are correct!  Would you mind choosing a name on this site so we don't have to call you "user11977"?

Answer (score 7):

The first part is fairly easy:

```
n = 20000;(*desired:n=20000*)
SeedRandom[42];
pos = RandomReal[{0, n^(1/3) - 1}, {n, 3}];
d = 0.8;
f = Nearest[pos];
pos1 = f[#, {Infinity, d}] & /@ pos;
```

**Edit**

The second part, using Combinatorica:

```
<< Combinatorica`
kNeighborhoods[pos_, d_, dist_] := Module[{f, pos1},
  f = Nearest[pos -> Automatic];
  pos1 = (Rest@f[#, {Infinity, d}]) & /@ pos;
  Neighborhood[pos1, #, dist] & /@ Range@Length@pos
  ]
d = 0.8;
dist = 4;
n = 20000;
pos = RandomReal[{0, n^(1/3) - 1}, {n, 3}];
kNeighborhoods[pos, d, dist]; // Timing
(*
 {1.006250, Null}
*)
```

Comment: I was not aware of this use of the NearestFunction. Is this gemstone documented? Furthermore, am I right that also points with distance equal to d are returned?

Comment: @user11977 Docs are here http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/UsingNearest.html

Comment: Fair enough. The documentation of NearestFunction does not mention this calling sequence leading me to assume it is undocumented ... Anyway, thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

I modified belisarius method to get first part:

```
n = 20000; SeedRandom[42];
pos = RandomReal[{0, n^(1/3) - 1}, {n, 3}];
d = 0.8;
rule = Thread[pos -> Range[n]];
f = Nearest[rule];
pos1 = f[#, {Infinity, d}] & /@ pos;
```

second part:

```
res = Union[
   Flatten[MapIndexed[
     With[{i = First[#2]}, Thread[i -> Select[#1, # > i &]]] &, 
     pos1]]];
g = Graph[res, DirectedEdges -> False];

res2 = Union[
    Sort /@ Flatten[
      Thread[{#, AdjacencyList[g, #, 4]}] & /@ VertexList[g], 
      1]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {1.075134, Null}

Comment: Thank you very much! I knew there had to be something better than GraphDistanceMatrix. AdjacencyList escaped me ...